# Combined brackets in list

Tags: java, list

I have list with different brackets:`[,],{,},(,)`
I need to merge them into double brackets

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        if (word.get(i).equals("("){
            word.set(i,"()");
        }
        if (word.get(i).equals("{"){
            word.set(i,"{}");
        }
        if (word.get(i).equals("["){
            word.set(i,"[]");
        }`
```

It works, but it remove some brackets. If before this there are like 107963, now it's 107952

Comment: I suggest you use a `switch(word.get(i))` statement.

Comment: show us the exception that had been thrown

Comment: this code doesn't merge anything, it tries to replace an opening brackets with a pair of brackets (and fails due to wrong String comparison) and doesn't touch existing closing brackets

Comment: That's exactly why it doesn't work

Comment: @Peter Lawrey the question is not a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Use  `if (word.get(i).equals "("){
                       word.set(i,"()");
    }`

Comment: @OferYuval can the OP update the question to show how this is not because `==` instead of `equals` being used.

Comment: It is not clear how you are counting the number of brackets. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I think what you are saying that  "equal instead of ==" is the answer to the question asked. While this is a fair and good answer, the question asked is completely different from "How do I compare strings in Java? " .